# Close areas sticking each other after the remesh

Tags: sculpting, topology, retopology, remesh

guys when ı use remesh close areas sticking each other. How can ı fix this?
[image]

[image]

Comment: use higher value?

Answer (score 0):

Second one helped me check the link

https://blenderartists.org/t/close-areas-sticking-each-other-after-the-remesh/1369598/2?u=faruk123gnc